# Download the file instead of opening new window

Tags: php, html, download

Users can upload documents and details on my form which gets saved into the database and a folder is created to hold the documents. They can upload .jpg .png .docx etc.. so not just images.

I now want to display links to these documents and when you click on the link it gives the option to save/open the file on your computer. Instead when I click the link it goes to a new page and shows the image there. but because they can upload word documents pdf etc.. you cant see these ina  new window.

The method im using now doesnt support on IE which is essential.

Code:

```
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

        $ref = $_POST["reference"];
        $query  = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM customers ";
        $query .= "WHERE reference = {$ref}";
        $results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        // Array to hold all results:
        $all = array();
        while ($customer_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
            // Append a new sub-array of the 3 other cols to
            // the main array's key by reference using the []
            // array append syntax
            $all[$customer_details['reference']][] = array(
                'doc1' => $customer_details['doc1'],
                'doc2' => $customer_details['doc2'],
                'doc3' => $customer_details['doc3']
            );
        }

        foreach ($all as $reference => $rows) {
          // Write out the reference, which was the array key
            echo $reference . "<br/>";
            // Then in a loop, write out the others
            foreach ($all as $reference => $rows) {
          // Write out the reference, which was the array key
            echo $reference . "<br/>";
            // Then in a loop, write out the others
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                echo  "<a href='docs/1111111/1/" . $row['doc1'] . "' download='" . $row['doc1'] . "' >file1</a><br/>";
                echo  "<a href='docs/1111111/1/" . $row['doc2'] . "' download='" . $row['doc2'] . "' >file2</a><br/>";
                echo  "<a href='docs/1111111/1/" . $row['doc3'] . "' download='" . $row['doc3'] . "' >file3</a><br/>";
            }

        }
    }
```

How can i get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add code lines into your .htaccess file on server.
You can change file type depending on extension (ex. doc)

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Here you got 3 options, from which this one is 3rd:
http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/forum/topic/force-a-file-to-download-instead-of-showing-up-in-the-browser